# How do I retrieve the underlying entity object from a Twig template in a Symfony2 entity field?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a form builder which creates a form with an 'entity' field type (let's call that entity MyBundle:MyEntity). MyEntity has a property entitled 'description'. In *addition* to the __tostring() method automatically called by Symfony2 that is used for the label of each radio button, I'd like to access the description property.

I've overridden the choice_widget block and attempted to get `{{ child.vars.value }}`, but that's just the ID of the entity rather than the object itself.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is even possible?

Comment: `$builder->add('myEntityProp', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'MyBundle:MyEntity', 'property' => 'title', 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => true ));`

Comment: Have you find a solution to your problem @Lusitanian ??? Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this problem, where `child.get('value')` and `child.vars.value` both return the ID instead of the entity itself. I've just switched to Symfony2.1 from 2.0, but I've changed a bunch of other stuff, too, so I'm not sure that the upgrade is to blame.

Comment: I've posted the answer that worked for me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029684/symfony2-entire-child-entity-in-form-and-twig-template/16359419#16359419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand well what you want to do exactly since you didn't provide any code but from what I understood you want to access the object of the child right?

If that's the case you can use child.get('value') and this will return the object

Which means you can call child.get('value').getDescription() or whatever function child object has

Comment: So I've been told, but that just returns the ID of the object, not the object itself.

Comment: I'm using this code and it perfectly returns the object.
Can you show us a little bit more code? like the template where you're accessing child