# Symfony2 - Entire child entity in form and Twig template

Tags: symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

In a Sonata admin form, I'd like to display all images related to the current object. Don't need to edit them.
I managed to get this working with an entity field type and its property option to select the image URL as label so I can call all pictures in the template :

```
->add('image', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Hop\HopBundle\Entity\Image',
    'property' => 'image_url',
    'query_builder' => function($er) use ($object) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->where('i.object = :object')
        ->setParameter('object', $object)
        ;
    },
    'expanded' => true,
))
```

.

```
{% for child in form %}
    <img src="{{ child.vars.label }}" alt="{{ child.vars.label }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

It's because it seems that the entity type only give label and one value to the template.

But I'd like to get also image width, descriptions, date, ... In other word : how can we get each entire related image object in the Twig template ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

So I googled it a lot and here's what worked for me (Symfony 2.2)
**Updated as @flu suggested in a comment**

```
{% for key, child in form %}
<div>
    {% set entity = form.vars.choices[key].data %}
    {{ form_widget(child) }}
    {{ form_label(child) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and `entity` is the child object.
As of Symfony 2.3 there will be just `form.vars.data`, if I understand correctly: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5023

Comment: Thank you! I think it's better to use `{% for key, child in form %}` and `{% set entity = form.vars.choices[key].data %}` because they share keys. Using `child.vars.value` as the key doesn't always work.

Answer (score 4):

I´ve spend the whole day to get a solution for this problem.

First I created a new FormType which extends the ChoiceType:

```
class NomineesType extends AbstractType
{
protected $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $submissionRepository = $this->em->getRepository('BundleName:Submission');
    $choices = $submissionRepository->findBy(array(
        'nominee' => true
    ));
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choices' => $choices
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'nominees';
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'choice';
}
}
```

Than I had to register the service:

```
services:
form.type.nominees:
    class: Bundle\Form\Type\NomineesType
    arguments:
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: nominees }
```

After that I added the new type to my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $game = $this->game;
    $builder->add('submission', 'nominees', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ));
    $builder->add('email');
}
```

Now I am able to get all properties in my twig-template:

```
{% block nominees_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            <li>
                {{ child.get('form').get('label').firstname }}
                {{ child.get('form').get('label').lastname }}
                {{ form_widget(child) }}
                {{ form_label(child) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        {# just let the choice widget render the select tag #}
        {{ block('choice_widget') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Because the choice list is returning only integer values I´ve created a new data transformer to transform the id of the choice into an entity:

```
class IntToEntityTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
private $om;

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $om
 */
public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
{
    $this->om = $om;
}

/**
 * Transforms an object (issue) to a string (number).
 *
 * @param  Issue|null $issue
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($issue)
{
    if (null === $issue) {
        return "";
    }

    return $issue->getNumber();
}

/**
 * Transforms a string (number) to an object (issue).
 *
 * @param  string $number
 * @return Issue|null
 * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (issue) is not found.
 */
public function reverseTransform($number)
{
    if (!$number) {
        return null;
    }

    $issue = $this->om
        ->getRepository('BundleName:Submission')
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => $number))
    ;

    if (null === $issue) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'An Submission with number "%s" does not exist!',
            $number
        ));
    }

    return $issue;
}
}
```

This data transformer is initialized in the build form method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new IntToEntityTransformer($this->em);
    $builder->add($builder->create('submission', 'nominees', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ))->addModelTransformer($transformer));
    $builder->add('email');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this problem with Symfony 2.3. Don't know how it works in 2.1.

In my case I had a entity choice (expanded and multiple) for which I needed to add the entitie's 'descripcion' field, next to the label of each choice.

I solved as follows:

1- created a custom type, whose parent is EntityType, and name 'xxxxxxx_form_reparacionnormalizada'

```
class ReparacionNormalizadaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class'        => 'xxxxxxxxx\Entity\TipoReparacion',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'xxxxxxx_form_reparacionnormalizada';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }
}
```

2- register the form type as service as usual

3- created a custom template as follows:

```
{% block xxxxxxx_form_reparacionnormalizada_widget %}
<ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes_choice_widget') }}>

    {% for id, child in form.children %}

    <li>
        {{ form_label(child, child.vars.label|default(null), { 'in_list_checkbox' : true, 'widget' : form_widget(child) } ) }}

        <span>{{ choices[id].data.descripcion }}</span>

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

4- in your sonata admin you use your custom type instead of `'entity'`

hope it helps

regards

javier